# Python client for Java APIs

Tags: python, client, response

I am working on a project which has all existing APIs in Java. I have to write a Python client for this. I am using requests library to call APIs. After getting the JSON response from the API should I return the dictionary or convert it into the required Python class?
I am new to Python so I am not sure which format would be better for Python users.

Comment: It depends the desired output. If this is a REST API, then usual format is application/json . If you are using Flask , you could use jsonify or json.dumps(python_dict)

Comment: I am writing a client for the API and getting response in JSON only. My question is what people expect from a client response- a dictionary or Python object?

Comment: Outside your application , the response should be json. Dictionary and python object only work with python